# Count rows mismatched while searching included tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize ^6.32.0 version and the dialect is'mssql'.

Search Condition is,

```
 let contentSearch: ContentSearch = {
                raw: false,
                distinct: true,
                where: { ActiveStatus: true, DeleteStatus: false, ProjectId: data.ProjectId },
                nest: true,
                attributes: [
                    'ProjectContentId',
                    'ProjectId',
                    'ContentId',
                    'ContentReviewName',
                    'ContentTodoList',
                    'ContentStartDate',
                    'ContentEndDate',
                    [db[data.Company].Sequelize.literal(participantCountQuery), 'ParticipantCount'],
                ],
                limit: data.PageSize,
                offset: (data.Page - 1) * data.PageSize,
            };
```

Include is,

```
private buildContentInclude(data: ContentListInput) {
    try {
        const degreeAttribute: string[] = ['DegreeId', 'Name'];
        const specialityAttribute: string[] = ['SpecialityId', 'Name'];
        const includeData = [
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentRole,
                attributes: ['RoleId'],
                as: 'ContentRole',
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db[data.Company].Role,
                        as: 'Role',
                        attributes: ['RoleName'],
                    },
                ],
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ContentStatus,
                as: 'ContentStatus',
                attributes: ['StatusName'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
               
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentUpload,
                as: 'ContentUploads',
                attributes: ['UploadDescription', 'UploadFile', 'DownloadContent', 'Version'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentParticipant,
                as: 'ContentParticipant',
                attributes: ['ProjectContentParticipantId', 'UserId'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db[data.Company].User,
                        attributes: ['UserId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ProfileImage', 'City', 'State'],
                        as: 'User',
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: db[data.Company].Degree,
                                as: 'DegreeData',
                                through: { attributes: [] },
                                attributes: degreeAttribute,
                            },
                            {
                                model: db[data.Company].Speciality,
                                as: 'SpecialityData',
                                through: { attributes: [] },
                                attributes: specialityAttribute,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];

        return { status: true, data: includeData };
    } catch (error) {
        logger.logError({ path: '', error: `${error}`, service: 'CONTENTSERVICE_BUILDCONTENTINCLUDE' });

        return { status: false };
    }
}
```

Here, ContentRole has an array of objects (a HasMany relationship). ContentStatus has an object with StatusName (a belong-to relationship).

I want to search the fields ContentId, ContentReviewName, StatusName, and RoleName with a like query ( [Op.like]: `%${search}%` ). I'm getting count mismatches while searching the included tables.

I tried this search:

```
private buildContentInclude(data: ContentListInput) {
    try {
        const degreeAttribute: string[] = ['DegreeId', 'Name'];
        const specialityAttribute: string[] = ['SpecialityId', 'Name'];
        const includeData = [
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentRole,
                attributes: ['RoleId'],
                as: 'ContentRole',
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db[data.Company].Role,
                        as: 'Role',
                        attributes: ['RoleName'],
                    },
                ],
                distinct: data.Search,
                separate: !data.Search,
                duplicating: false,
                required: false,
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ContentStatus,
                as: 'ContentStatus',
                attributes: ['StatusName'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
                distinct: data.Search,
                duplicating: false,
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentUpload,
                as: 'ContentUploads',
                attributes: ['UploadDescription', 'UploadFile', 'DownloadContent', 'Version'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
                distinct: data.Search,
                separate: !data.Search,
                duplicating: false,
            },
            {
                model: db[data.Company].ProjectContentParticipant,
                as: 'ContentParticipant',
                attributes: ['ProjectContentParticipantId', 'UserId'],
                where: globalData.activeDeleteWhere,
                required: false,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db[data.Company].User,
                        attributes: ['UserId', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ProfileImage', 'City', 'State'],
                        as: 'User',
                        include: [
                            {
                                model: db[data.Company].Degree,
                                as: 'DegreeData',
                                through: { attributes: [] },
                                attributes: degreeAttribute,
                            },
                            {
                                model: db[data.Company].Speciality,
                                as: 'SpecialityData',
                                through: { attributes: [] },
                                attributes: specialityAttribute,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];

        return { status: true, data: includeData };
    } catch (error) {
        logger.logError({ path: '', error: `${error}`, service: 'CONTENTSERVICE_BUILDCONTENTINCLUDE' });

        return { status: false };
    }
}

private buildSearchQuery(search: string) {
    try {
        const queryFields = [
            'ContentId',
            'ContentReviewName',
            '$ContentStatus.StatusName$',
            '$ContentRole.Role.RoleName$',
        ];

        const searchQuery = queryFields.map((field) => ({ [field]: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } }));

        return { status: true, data: searchQuery };
    } catch (error) {
        logger.logError({ path: '', error: `${error}`, service: 'CONTENTSERVICE_BUILDSEARCHQUERY' });

        return { status: false };
    }
}


   contentSearch.include = includeResult.data;

        if (data.Search) {
            const searchQueryResult = this.buildSearchQuery(data.Search);
            if (!searchQueryResult.status || !searchQueryResult.data) {
                finalResult.result.Message = messages.catchError;
                return finalResult;
            }

            contentSearch.where = {
                ...contentSearch.where,
                [Op.or]: searchQueryResult.data,
            };
        }
```

Comment: How is SQL server relevant to this question?